# How to get Document Thumbnail via Rest API (SharePoint online - classic experience) for excel, word and pdf files?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, classic-experience, thumbnail

I'm looking at getting a thumbnail image of documents when uploaded into a document library. I can see the thumbnail preview when I click on ellipses (...) context menu of the document.
Is there a way to somehow get this document using Rest API?

I did try the below for a .png file.

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?path=https%3A%2F%2Ftenant.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2Ftest%2FTestWork.png
```

It worked for .png file but not for word, excel or PDF documents.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you know rest api but This should return the url of the thumbnail -->

/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('title')/items(itemid)?$select=EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl

Comment: Hi Billy, I guess i know some little rest api. Tried _api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items(1)?$select=id got some result back but tried  /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('title')/items(1)?$select=EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl but nothing
am i missing something?

Comment: Actually tried _api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items(1)?select=EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl and gopt some results but for some ServerRedirectedEmbedUri  returns null